# Binary Tree Postfix Calculator

Tags: java, binary-tree, calculator, infix-notation, postfix-notation

I'm making a Postfix calculator where I must use stack objects and a Binary tree during the translation of an expression from infix to a parse tree during the evaluation of a postfix expression.

Can someone please translate?

I have developed a postfix calculator method and I've developed a method that changes an expression from infix to postfix, but I don't understand what I am being asked to do. I can enter an expression in infix and calculate it fine as well as convert it to postfix, but I cannot determine what exactly I am being asked to create here.

An example of how to essentially do this in pseudocode would be very helpful or just an  explanation of how to store a mathematical expression into a binary tree as well as how to evaluate an expression in a binary tree with stack into a parse tree.

I'll also say I'm a little unsure what a parse tree is.

Any explanation would be very much appreciated.

It is an assignment for a class, so it can be seen here if this was inadequate information: http://www.cs.gsu.edu/jbhola/csc3410/Spring13/assign6_expre_tree.html

My main point here is I just don't quite understand what I'm supposed to do or how I'm supposed to do it. We weren't taught how to program any of this and we lack a textbook so I'm just kind of blindly trying to wrap my head around the whole project :/

Comment: I assume you are being asked to build a binary tree representation of the expressions you are given.  Strictly you don't need a binary tree to evaluate the expression but this is the purpose of the exercise so you cannot drop it.  You might not have a textbook, but you should have google which is likely to be better anyway.

Comment: I have googled, and what I have found is a method for which to read a binary tree expression in postfix, however not an explanation on how to set such a thing up or calculate it from the tree directly :c

Comment: I would worry first about a) what is a binary tree and b) how do you build one.  How to perform a calculation on such a tree is perhaps too trivial to include in a post.

Comment: Some things are so trivial, your brain rejects it. Everything else seems complicated so it must be all complicated. ;)  I have given you an answer as a hint.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. Learn to make a binary tree, then simply read the binary tree objects in postfix form. 

So I assume this mean I need to learn how to store an infix expression into a binary tree properly then just evaluated using a postfix reading method. Since I already know how to read a tree postfix, all I need to make is an infix expression storing method for the tree! This is MUCH clearer now! Thank you :D

Comment: But wait... When does the stack come in then?

Comment: See my answer, but once you have the tree, valuating it is trivial.

Comment: The Stack is needed for your infix parsing.

Comment: Your question is hioplessly confused. You need to (1) convert infix to postfix, during which you can use a binary tree, although you don't really need to, and (2) evaluate the resulting postfix, at which point you don't need anything more than a stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a node like AddNode which has two values

```
class AddNode {
    final double a, b;

    double value() {
       return // how could you return the value of this node?
    }
}
```

Making it more generic

```
 interface Node { double value(); }

 class AddNode implements Node {
      final Node a, b;

      double value() {
          return // something which gives the value of this node.
      }
 }
```